# How to configure docker containers to get access to them using VPN?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn, openvpn, docker-network

I have simple docker-compose.yml with Apache server and OpenVPN:

```
version: '2'
services:

  apache:
    image: 'bitnami/apache:latest'
    ports:
      - '1889:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    volumes:
      - ./mysite:/app

  openvpn:
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    image: kylemanna/openvpn
    container_name: openvpn
    ports:
      - "1194:1194/udp"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./openvpn-data/conf:/etc/openvpn
```

After configured kylemanna/openvpn I can connect to VPN from host but how to make Apache available through VPN? So for example:
I connect to VPN and from my browser I want to see under e.g 10.0.0.3:1889 my website.

Edit:
ozlevka's suggestion helped me a bit but now I want to add service which works through UDP but with current configuration it's not working. I tested my UDP port from localhost and it works but through VPN not responding even on telnet. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your containers is in the same network. If you can open tunel to openvpn container then you be able to query you apache container as `http://apache:8080` or `https://apache:8443`

Comment: It's not working with or without VPN. I can connect to apache with localhost:1889 and it doesn't matter if I am connected to VPN or not.

Comment: It helped me a bit. I didn't create kylemanna/openvpn with docker-compose but with standard docker and now is working when I used http://192.168.255.6:1889 but I want to add another service which works through UDP but with currently configuration it is not working. How to do this?